# RISC-V Compressed Instructions: Can compiler be forced to align 32bit instructions on 32bit boundaries?

Tags: gcc, riscv

We are implementing a custom RISC-V CPU.  We start with Rocket core as the base and heavily modify.

Our first version was based on 2016 Rocket Chip, which did not have compressed instructions.  We are now porting to 2017, which does.  We recently discovered that the 2017 version allows 32bit instructions to be aligned on 16bit boundaries -- which means that a single instruction can be split across two cache lines!

For our implementation, this causes non-trivial issues.

Things are fine as long as 32bit instructions are not split across cache lines.

Can GCC be forced to align all 32 bit instructions on 32bit boundaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no support for this in the toolchain.  Our GCC port would actually be incapable of doing this, as alignment is handled at link time (there's a blog on this: https://www.sifive.com/blog/2017/08/28/all-aboard-part-3-linker-relaxation-in-riscv-toolchain/).  While you could add support for this to the toolchain, it'd render the C extension effectively useless so you're probably better off treating this as a core that doesn't support RVC.

Comment: Thanks Palmer.  I appreciate taking the time out to answer.  Unfortunately for us, this may end up being harsher than it may appear on the surface.  We have 16 harts per core, and that implies that we have to do special things around instruction handling.  Splitting an instruction across cache lines throws a serious monkey wrench into that :-)   Were there any studies done on how much of a benefit was gained from 16bit alignment of 32bit instructions?

Comment: If you just ignore the C extension then instructions are defined to be 32-bit aligned, so that's probably the way to go.

I don't think there was an explicit study done to decide on 16-bit alignment of 32-bit instructions, but IIRC there was a quick benchmark run done and it erroded between 25% and 50% of the benefit of the C extension -- though much more toolchain work would need to be done to get a real number.

Comment: This should be easy to implement in the assembler.  Force 32 bit alignment of all code segments and insert nops before 32 bit instructions to establish alignment if needed.